# Firefox issue with html, body and height: 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, animation

I am working on a website which is a landing page. Website has 3 sections and arrows to navigate from one section to another and the last arrow is in the footer which has functionality of "back to the top".

My code is working in the Chrome but not in the Firefox and I am having issue with animations. Solution for this is to set height:100% but then I am facing a problem with animations issue because they are not displayed. I am using Wow for animations.

Below is my function which navigates to sections smoothly:

```
  $(function () {
            $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function () {
                if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                    var hrefLink = $(this).attr('href');
                    var str = document.URL;
                    var n = str.lastIndexOf('#');
                    var result = str.substring(0, n + 1);

                    var target = $(this.hash);
                    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');

                    $("html, body").animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, "slow");

                    history.pushState(document.URL, '', "");
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) example to better illustrate the issue you're having?